# Find the generating function for ${{6}\choose{1}}, 2{{6}\choose{2}}, 3{{6}\choose{3}} ,..., 6{{6}\choose{6}},...$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Find the generating function for ${{6}\choose{1}}, 2{{6}\choose{2}}, 3{{6}\choose{3}} ,..., 6{{6}\choose{6}},...$

What I've been doing:

${{6}\choose{1}} + 2{{6}\choose{2}}x + 3{{6}\choose{3}}x^2+ ... +6{{6}\choose{6}}x^5+... = \sum_{i=1} ^{\infty}{{6}\choose{i}}ix^{i-1}$

I'm really stuck there, I thought of using the binomial theorem but I can't think of a way to apply it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $\binom{6}{7}$ then? I think you'll find this is a finite sum...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^i\implies \\{d(1+x)^n\over dx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\cdot ix^{i-1}$$also$$\binom{n}{m}=0\quad,\quad m>n$$